# UIScrollView menu and parallax effect

Tags: iphone, menu, uiscrollview, parallax

I need to create a main menu for my app with a UIScrollView. I have some images inside it that can be clicked. When I scroll the UIScrollView I need that on the background there are other two views that move creating a parallax effect.
Can someone provide me a sample code? I'm trying to work with

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

but I cannot find any productive example about applying on my project.

Answer (score 4):

How's this? The imageView will scroll up half as fast as the UIScrollView.

```
    float y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGRect imageFrame = self.imageView.frame;
    imageFrame.origin.y = y/2;
    self.imageView.frame = imageFrame;
```

Answer (score 2):

This GitHub repository has an amazing implementation that works quite well:
https://github.com/ralfbernert/RBParallaxScrolling

Here's my test of the code, using a UIScrollView with pagination (in the front) and an image in the background:
http://clrk.it/211o3h0A053m

The bit of code that does this parallax trick works as follows:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == _scrollView) {
        float speedFactor = _headerImageScrollView.contentSize.width / _scrollView.contentSize.width;
        [_headerImageScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(speedFactor * _scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
    }
}
```

In this code, I've got a UIScrollView that contains a UIImageView; I call this `_headerImageScrollView`.

In front of it, I have a second UIScrollView with pagination and the three labels. That one's called `_scrollView`.